# Jmeter threads are not ramping down

Tags: jmeter

I am doing a load test of 300 Virtual users on an application. Previously my users were ramping down and test seems to be finished with in time But now as I jump to 500 user test my users are not ramping down and test keep running for like infinite amount of time. Again I run the test with 300 users, 37 users are still in the system and are not ramping down. Hence my test did not finish.

These are the things that I tried to fix,

- Increase the HEAP size in jmeter.properties file.
- Cleared the cache and rebooted the services (i.e. SQLSERVER and
  collab services)

Can anybody suggest that where Iam doing wrong?

Comment: Do all 500/300 threads continue to work endlessly or just some of them?

Comment: Could you show your jmeter.log?

Comment: Some of them are unable to do anything that is why they are still in the system. 37 users out of 300 hanged in JMeter.

Comment: https://1drv.ms/f/s!ApO2fWm29OU6aHGr3tPM2RQJrX0

Comment: Please hit above link in order to access jmeter log file

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case your server fails to provide response, by default JMeter will wait for the response **forever**, it might explain the situation you're running into.

There is "Timeouts" section on the "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler (or even better [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults) configuration element) where you can set maximum values for Connect / Response, in case if they are exceeded JMeter will automatically mark the sampler as failed and proceed.

Alternative options:

1. You can set maximum test duration using "Scheduler" section of the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

   [image]
2. There is [Runtime Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller) where you can define for how long its children are allowed to be run.